# How to turn off LED lights/flashlight on camera in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

we are in the middle of project - we use USB microscope Dino Lite to take some pictures but we need to set it to specific setting. And only thing I cannot find out is how to turn off LED lights (I mean like flash light). Right now I'm like here:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 2592)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1944)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -8)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT, 0) # does not work!

result, image = cap.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I guess that

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT, 0)
```

work with some LED but not with the 'front one' that I need to turn off...if you know what I mean.

OS WIN10/11

Answer (score 0):

Try using `guvcview` to turn off the LED light. It should stay off when you open the camera in opencv.

Comment: Thank you but this `guvcview` is maybe Linux thing...? Not sure, really, but I did not specify OS in original question, sorry for that. Edited. I am working in Windows.